# Solving system of differential equation with laplace transformation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I've got a very simple question which I'm failing to solve .
Here it is:

> $x'=4x+2y, y'=2x+4y, x(0) =-1, y(0)=2$

I'm just starting to learn Laplace Transformation and still very weak at it.
Can anyone help me by showing steps which will lead me to the final solution?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Before showing my solution to your problem, I would like you to show your attempts to solve the problem. The only way to learn to solve problems in math is by solving problems. We problem solvers at MathSE will be happy to help you, but we like to see where you are stuck so we know where we need to help.

Answer (score 0):

$(x+y)'=6(x+y)\implies x+y=ce^{6t}$. So $x'=4x+2(ce^{6t}-x)=2x+2ce^{6t}$. Write $x=c_0e^{2t}+c_1e^{6t}$, then $4c_1=2c\implies c_1=\dfrac c2$. Hence $x=c_0e^{2t}+\dfrac c2e^{6t}$, which determines the solution for y. The constants may be determined by plugging in the initial values.